# How do I create date input field with calendar in Magneto2? [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, forms, date, calendar, input

I want to create a date input field with calendar control where I can change year and month by drop down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here I got the solution:

```
<div class="control customer-dob">
    <input type="text" 
           class="input-text required-entry hasDatepicker" 
           id="calendar_inputField" 
           name="dob"
           aria-required="true" />
    <script>
        require([
            "jquery",
            "mage/calendar"
        ], function ($) {
            $("#calendar_inputField").calendar({
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                yearRange: "1970:2050",
                buttonText: "Select Date",
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Preview:

[image: Solution Preview]

You can use in layout processor for shipping like this

```
  $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
     ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['dob'] = [
     'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
     'config'   => [
        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/date',
        'id' => 'dob',
        'options' => [
            'changeYear'=> true,
            'changeMonth'=> true,
            'yearRange' => '1950:2050',
        ],
     ],
     'validation' => [
        'required-entry' => true
     ],
     'label' => __('Date of Birth'),
     'required' => true,
     'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.dob',
     'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
     'visible' => true,
     'sortOrder' => 55
     ];
```

For TimePicker with date

```
  $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
     ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['schedule'] = [
     'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
     'config'   => [
        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/date',
        'id' => 'schedule',
        'options' => [
            'timeInput' => true,
            'timeFormat' => "HH:mm:ss",
            'showsTime' => true
        ],
     ],
     'validation' => [
        'required-entry' => true
     ],
     'label' => __('Schedule Time'),
     'required' => true,
     'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.schedule',
     'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
     'visible' => true,
     'sortOrder' => 98,
     'id' => 'schedule'
     ];
```

[image]

Comment: Great work .... thanks !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\getDateInput() function I came up with this code which works well and is probably more "correct" than the current answer.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Date'
)->setName(
  'date-range[from]'
)->setId(
  'from-date'
)->setValue(
  ''
)->setImage(
  $this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Theme::calendar.png')
)->setDateFormat(
  'y-MM-dd'
)->getHtml();
```

Comment: Hey Marc How to add required to this code?

Comment: @MagEGY, have you got any solution for required field ?

Comment: Try `->setExtraParams('required')` and if that doesn't work follow the trail of code from Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Date and see where it goes.

Answer (score 1):

If someones looks for that code in `xml` here is it:

```
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="schedule" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
        <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.custom_attributes</item>
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
            <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/date</item>
            <item name="id" xsi:type="string">schedule</item>
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="timeInput" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="validation"  xsi:type="array">
            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Schedule Time</item>
        <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.custom_attributes.schedule</item>
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="id" xsi:type="string">schedule</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

I hope that it can save some time for you.

**PS:** the `children` node is not a required if you are adding this code in the existing container.

Answer (score 0):

I use only one line code and I got calendar display.

```
<input type="date" name="eventdate" id="eventdate" placeholder="Event Date" value="" class="input-text"  data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-date':true}" >
```