# How can i add date and month text box with validation(No calender)

Tags: magento2, validation, date, varien

How can I add Magento custom validation for `month` and `date` text box?
These two are input text box user can enter the number and I have to validate it via custom validation.
Don't want a calender.

```
<div class="field date field-dob">
                    <label class="label" for="dob"><span>Your Birthday</span></label>
                    <div class="input-box customer-dob">
                        <div class="dob-month">
                            <input type="text" id="month" name="month" value="12" title="Month" class="input-text validate-custom">
                            <label for="month">MM</label>
                        </div><div class="dob-day">
                            <input type="text" id="day" name="day" value="12" title="Day" class="input-text validate-custom">
                            <label for="day">DD</label>
                        </div><div class="dob-year" style="display:none;">
                            <input value="1900" type="text" id="year" name="year" title="Year" class="input-text validate-custom" autocomplete="off">
                            <label for="year">YYYY</label>
                        </div>    <div class="dob-full" style="display:none;">
                            <input type="hidden" id="dob" name="dob">
                        </div>

                        <div class="validation-advice" style="display:none;"></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

`script`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
     var customer_dob = new Varien.DOB('.customer-dob', false, 
   '%m/%e/%Y');
   //]]>
 </script>
```

This code didn't work for me.

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/149392/how-do-i-create-date-input-field-with-calendar-in-magneto2-solved link.. I think it will help you

Comment: why you not use date picker?

Comment: @dhiren vasoya , date picker in my case is useless just want simple textbox for month and date

Comment: @summu please find the below given answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/274744/52244, hope this will match your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Add Magento custom validation to a form field using adding  a new rule using `$.validator.addMethod`

using `$.validator.addMethod` we can **create number of custom rules and via class name we can access those custom rules**.

so back to the question,  need of question is without using calendar validate input fields like days/month/year.

so assuming where you adding these days/month/year fields that wrap with form tag, In this form magento default validation added `data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}`' or via js.

create all days/month/year fields under form or add below html code

```
<div class="field date field-dob"  data-mage-init='{
        "Vendor_Module/js/custom-validation-dob":{
            "day" : "[name=\"day\"]",
            "month" : "[name=\"month\"]",
            "year" : "[name=\"year\"]",
            "classPrefix": "custom-dob",
            "maxYearDiff": 150
        }
    }'>
    <label class="label" for="dob">
        <span><?= __('Your Birthday'); ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="input-box customer-dob">
         <div class="dob-day">
             <label for="day"><?= __('DD'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="day" name="day"  title="<?= __('Day'); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        
        <div class="dob-month">
             <label for="month"><?= __('MM'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="month" name="month" title="<?= __('Month'); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
       
        <div class="dob-year">
            <label for="year"><?= __('YYYY'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" id="year" name="year" title="<?= __('Year'); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" autocomplete="off">
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**Alter or update the HTML as your need expect name attribute of input field. if need to modify name attribute too then do same change in**

```
data-mage-init='{
    "Vendor_Module/js/custom-validation-dob":{
        "day" : "[name=\"day\"]",
        "month" : "[name=\"month\"]",
        "year" : "[name=\"year\"]",
        "classPrefix": "custom-dob",
        "maxYearDiff": 150
    }
}'
```

**as well with respective fields.**

Now create a js file `custom-validation-dob.js` under your module something like that   `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/custom-validation-dob.js` the paste below js code

```
define([
    'jquery',   
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/validate',
    'mage/translate'
], function($){
    'use strict';

    var enterValueIsNumeric = function (input) {
       return (input - 0) == input && input.length > 0;
    }
        
    return function(config, element) {
        var dayObj = $(element).find(config.day || '[name="day"]');
        var monthObj = $(element).find(config.month || '[name="month"]');
        var yearObj = $(element).find(config.year || '[name="year"]');        
        var classPrefix = config.classPrefix || 'custom';
        var maxYearDiff = config.maxYearDiff ||  100; // max limit for year gap

        $.validator.addMethod(
            classPrefix+"-day-validate",
            function(value, element) {
                var result = false,
                    validatorObj = this,
                    isElementOptional = this.optional(element),
                    days = 31; // just to assume no value set on year and month fields
                
                var year = yearObj.val();
                var month = monthObj.val();
                
                var currentDateObj = new Date();
                var maxMonth = currentDateObj.getMonth() + 1;
                var maxYear = currentDateObj.getFullYear();
                var currentDay = currentDateObj.getDate();
                
                var message = $.mage.__("Please enter valid day value in this field.");
                
               
                if(enterValueIsNumeric(value)) {
                    if(year && month){ //Checks days in the specific month with year
                        days = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
                    }
                    
                    result = days >= value;
                    if(result && year == maxYear && month == maxMonth) { // for current year & month
                        result = currentDay >= value;
                        message = $.mage.__("Entered day value will be less then or equal to %1 that is current day because Entered Year and Month value respectively equal to current year and month value.").replace('%1', currentDay);
                    }
                } 
                     
                if (!result) {
                    validatorObj.customDayMessage = message;
                }                
                return isElementOptional || result;
            }, function () {
                return this.customDayMessage;
            }            
        );

        $.validator.addMethod(
            classPrefix+"-month-validate",
            function(value, element) {
                var result = false,
                    validatorObj = this,
                    isElementOptional = this.optional(element);
                var year = yearObj.val();
                
                var currentDateObj = new Date();
                var maxMonth = currentDateObj.getMonth() + 1;
                var maxYear = currentDateObj.getFullYear();
               
                var message = $.mage.__("Please enter valid month value in this field.");
                if(enterValueIsNumeric(value)) {
                    result = ( value >= 1 && value <= 12);
                    if(result && year == maxYear) { // For current year 
                        result = ( value <= maxMonth);
                        message = $.mage.__("Entered month value will be less then or equal to %1 that is current month because Entered Year value is equal to current year value.").replace('%1', maxMonth);
                    } 
                } 
                           
                if (!result) {
                    validatorObj.customMonthMessage = message;
                }
                return isElementOptional || result; 
            }, function () {
                return this.customMonthMessage;
            }
        );

        $.validator.addMethod(
            classPrefix+"-year-validate",
            function(value, element) {
                var result = false,
                    validatorObj = this,
                    isElementOptional = this.optional(element),
                    prevDateObj = new Date(),
                    currentDateObj = new Date();
                    
                prevDateObj.setFullYear(prevDateObj.getFullYear() - maxYearDiff);
                currentDateObj.setFullYear(currentDateObj.getFullYear());
                
                var minYear = prevDateObj.getFullYear();
                var maxYear = currentDateObj.getFullYear(); // because DOB value will be less then the current year
                var message = $.mage.__("Please enter valid year value in this field and year value will be in between %1 and %2").replace('%1', minYear).replace('%2', maxYear);
                               
                if(enterValueIsNumeric(value)) {
                    result = (value.length == 4 && value >= minYear && value <= maxYear ); // always be year value in 4 digit
                }
                                
                if (!result) {
                    validatorObj.customYearMessage = message;
                }
                return isElementOptional || result;
            }, function () {
                return this.customYearMessage;
            }
            
        );     
        
        // binding class with respective element to apply validation rule properly.
        dayObj.addClass(classPrefix+"-day-validate");
        monthObj.addClass(classPrefix+"-month-validate");
        yearObj.addClass(classPrefix+"-year-validate");
    }
});
```

using these 2 code set, first html markup and second magento custom js will help to **validate calendar like function**. and these rules are linked also so proper validation come in picture hope this will match all you expectation mention in question.

### Add on -

For future reuse of this custom js with valid name instead of full path, **alias the js path with a good name**.

So create a requirejs config file `requirejs-config.js` in your module `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` if not exist and add below code

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "customValidationForDMY": "Vendor_Module/js/custom-validation-dob" // D = Day,M = Month, Y = Year
        }
    }
};
```

then in above mention html code update

```
data-mage-init='{
    "Vendor_Module/js/custom-validation-dob":{
        "day" : "[name=\"day\"]",
        "month" : "[name=\"month\"]",
        "year" : "[name=\"year\"]",
        "classPrefix": "custom-dob",
        "maxYearDiff": 150
    }
}'
```

with

```
data-mage-init='{
    "customValidationForDMY":{
        "day" : "[name=\"day\"]",
        "month" : "[name=\"month\"]",
        "year" : "[name=\"year\"]",
        "classPrefix": "custom-dob",
        "maxYearDiff": 150
    }
}'
```

In given sample I used **Vendor_Module**, In your case this will be change with your respective module name.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try already existing validations? They are already here and ready to use:

For the month field add the classes:

> validate-number validate-greater-than-zero less-than-equals-to-12

For the day field add the classes:

> validate-number validate-greater-than-zero less-than-equals-to-30

For the year field add the classes:

> validate-number greater-than-equals-to-1950 less-than-equals-to-2050

Add `data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'` to your form tag.

You can check more [here](https://inchoo.net/magento-2/validate-custom-form-in-magento-2/)

Answer (score 0):

**STEP1:** You need to `data-mage-init` attribute in your custom form. Refer below code

```
<form class="form contact"
      action=""
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-mage-init='{
    "validation":{},
     "customValidationMethod":{}
}'>
    <div class="field date field-dob">
        <label class="label" for="dob"><span>Your Birthday</span></label>
        <div class="input-box customer-dob">
            <div class="dob-month">
                <input type="text" id="month" name="month" value="29" title="Month" class="input-text validate-custom custom-date">
                <label for="month">MM</label>
            </div><div class="dob-day">
                <input type="text" id="day" name="day" value="2" title="Day" class="input-text validate-custom custom-month">
                <label for="day">DD</label>
            </div><div class="dob-year">
                <input value="2008" type="text" id="year" name="year" title="Year" class="input-text validate-custom custom-year" autocomplete="off">
                <label for="year">YYYY</label>
            </div>    <div class="dob-full" style="display:none;">
                <input type="hidden" id="dob" name="dob">
            </div>
            <div class="validation-advice" style="display:none;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button class="action subscribe type="submit">
            <span>Submit</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And add `custom-date`, `custom-month`, `custom-year` classes for respective fields to add logic in validation method.

**STEP2:** Add `requirejs-config.js` in your custom module `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` with following code,

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            customValidationMethod: "Vendor_Module/js/customValidationMethod"
        }
    }
};
```

**STEP3:** Place the `customValidationMethod.js` file in `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/customValidationMethod.js` with validation logic

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/validate',
    'mage/translate'
], function($){
    'use strict';

    return function() {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            "custom-date",
            function(value, element) {
                var year = jQuery('.custom-year').val();
                var month = jQuery('.custom-month').val();
                var daysIn = 31;
                if(year && month){
                    //Checks days in the specific month with year
                    daysIn = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
                }
                return this.optional(element) || (daysIn >= value);
            },
            $.mage.__("Please enter valid date")
        );

        $.validator.addMethod(
            "custom-month",
            function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || (value >= 1 && value <= 12);
            },
            $.mage.__("Please enter valid month")
        );

        $.validator.addMethod(
            "custom-year",
            function(value, element) {
                //Add your required year
                return this.optional(element) || (value >= 1950 && value <= 2019);
            },
            $.mage.__("Please enter valid year")
        );
    }
});
```

Please add `required` class to the input box if the field is required. And don't forgot to run these CLI Commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```